# php exec with sudo fails on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, sudo

I am running CentOS 6, as httpd is executed as user 'apache'. For security reasons, I want to use sudo to be executed via exec as user 'aq':

```
<?php exec("/usr/bin/sudo -u aq somescript.sh",$output,$return_val);?>
```

With visudo I have added the following line:

```
apache ALL = (aq) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Furthermore I temporary gave apache as login shell (/bin/bash), to be able to test

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u aq somescript.sh
```

directly which worked.

php exec fails as $return_val delivers a '1' if sudo is invoked.

Comment: sestatus returns disabled, so SELINUX is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out this line from /etc/sudoers

> Defaults    requiretty

I'v tested your case in few ways ant this one gives me success.